# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/asd eroor

Tags: java, mysql, exception, jdbc

```
import java.sql.*;

class Mysqll{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/asd","root","qwerty");
        Statement st = con.createStatement();

        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from abc");

        while(rs.next())
        {
            System.out.println(rs.getInt(1) + "   " + rs.getString(2));
        }
        con.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to jdbc programming. So plese help.
Getting this Exception while running the program.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc::mysql://localhost:3306/asd
```

I had copied mysql-connector.jar file into jre/lib/ext folder.
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Already visited that ... but didn't found any solution related to my problem

Comment: How about if you only put a single colon between `jdbc` and `mysql`?

Comment: voting to close: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a **simple typographical error**.

Comment: Do not put your JDBC driver in the `lib/ext` folder, it is deprecated and will be removed, and can cause version conflicts and other hard to diagnose problems.

Answer (score 0):

The connection string being passed to DriverManager is a URL. The formatting matters, and your problem is due to an extra colon between `jdbc` and `mysql` (verified by testing on my own system).

Replace `jdbc::mysql:` with `jdbc:mysql:`.